# How can we calculate the frequency of specific words for each row in the dataframe with R?

Tags: rstudio

I'm working on a data that each sentence is in separate rows in dataframe. I want to determine word frequency in each row with a word list that I have created. Then I would like to add these values to my dataframe as a new variable in R.

Comment: Provide code example and data example what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer which can help you to solve your problem.

```
a <- c("asfef", "qwerty", "yuiop[", "b", "stuff.blah.yech")
a <- as.data.frame(a)
a$LENGHT <- nchar(as.character(a$a))
```

If you have your data please share if you are not getting this example let me know.